# MouseWheel EventToCommand for StackPanel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I have a StackPanel with a Listview inside.
I want to be able to scroll inside the window, to change the selectedItem.

**To clarify;**
I want to change my ViewModels SelectedItem when the mousewheel is scrolled.

I cannot find a way to bind my command to the event through the EventToCommand

I Thought it could be pulled off by doing

```
<StackPanel>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseWheel">
        <cmd:EventToCommand PassEventArgsToCommand="True" 
              Command="{Binding MouseScrollCommand}">
        </cmd:EventToCommand >
    </i:EventTrigger>
    <ListView/>
</StackPanel>
```

But that gets me an error stating that the eventtrigger can only be assinged to a UIElement.

Then I tried inside the ListView - which also didn't work.

How can I bind an event (with args) to a scrollwheel event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're almost there, but you need to wrap your EventTrigger in the [System.Windows.Interactivity Interaction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interactivity.interaction(v=expression.40).aspx) class:

```
<StackPanel>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseWheel">
            <cmd:EventToCommand PassEventArgsToCommand="True" 
                  Command="{Binding MouseScrollCommand}">
            </cmd:EventToCommand >
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <ListView/>
</StackPanel>
```

You should find that will raise the event, and call your command.

The Interaction class handles the events on the associated object, and propagates them through the EventTriggers.

Comment: No worries. If this solved your problem, don't forget to mark the question as answered :)

Comment: Oh sorry - thought I did :) - fixed